# Removing elements from an unordered_multimap

Tags: c++

I have an unordered_multimap that represents an adjacency list, and several edges that have self loops. For example:

edges_ might be:

```
edges_.insert(Edges::value_type(1, std::make_pair(1, 0.0)));
edges_.insert(Edges::value_type(1, std::make_pair(1, 0.0)));
edges_.insert(Edges::value_type(1, std::make_pair(1, 0.0)));
edges_.insert(Edges::value_type(1, std::make_pair(2, 0.0)));
```

I would like to remove the 3 duplicate (1, (1, 0.0)) values. If I break after the edges_.erase(it) line only one of the three duplicates is removed.

If I advance through the iteration, regardless of whether I increment the iterator or not, it seems to crash after that. How can I remove all three?

```
template <typename T_NodeLabel, typename T_EdgeWeight>
class Graph
{
public:
    using NodeId = unsigned int;
    using Nodes = std::unordered_map<NodeId, T_NodeLabel>;
    using AdjacencyList = std::pair<NodeId, T_EdgeWeight>;
    using Edges = std::unordered_multimap<NodeId, AdjacencyList>;
    void RemoveSelfLoops(NodeId node)
    {
        auto edges = edges_.equal_range(node);
        for (auto it = edges.first; it != edges.second;)
        {
            if (it->second.first == node)
            {
                edges_.erase(it);
            }
            else
            {
                ++it;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    Nodes nodes_;
    Edges edges_;
};
```

Comment: Think about what happens when you find the first duplicate, especially what happens to the iterator. You may want to check [an `erase` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) (especially check what `erase` returns).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After call to `erase`, your iterator is invalidated. And then you try to use it on the next iteration.

You need to use a return value of `erase` as the new iterator.